# Change the gray color of the dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im using the folloing dialog and I want to change the gray color for the button and the header to blue,
how should I do that?

This is the code

```
 $dialog.dialog({
            autoOpen: false, 
            modal: true,    
            show: {effect: 'fade', duration: 2000},
            buttons: {
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511609/customize-the-style-for-specific-jquery-ui-dialog-box-not-all-the-dialogs

Comment: @Andrew-Ive already try with    $("#dialog").parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").css("background", "#1C1C1C"); which is not working for the header...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would style your buttons.

```
  open: function (e, ui) {
        $(this).parent().find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-button")
            .addClass("orange");
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane .ui-dialog-buttonset .orange {
   /* put styling here */
}
```

For title bar:

```
.ui-dialog > .ui-widget-header {background: red;}
```

Comment: Hi Ali,wheh I use the code which you provided for JS I got error anonymus function is used as declaration,any idea how to overcome it?

Comment: Thanks Ali Voted up!,this is exactly what I need for the buttons,what about the  gray line in the header ,is it possible to change it either?

Comment: Hi Ali,im talking about .ui-dialog-titlebar ,how should i add it to your CSS ?when i add it to the css that you provide its not working...

Comment: Hey @JohnJerrby, see my edit and if I helped you, +1 and mark as solve.

Comment: That line of CSS allows you to change title bar color. I tested it :)

Answer (score 2):

JqueryUI has ThemeRoller which lets you style it's appearance. You can also do it manually but you should check it out first:

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code - 
    $div.dialog({
       modal: true,
        maxHeight:500,
    }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background","blue");